# Excel indexmatch, vlookup

Tags: excel, indexing, match, vlookup

I have a holiday calendar for several years in one table. Can anyone help – How to arrange this data by week and show holiday against week? I want to reference this data in other worksheets and hence arranging this way will help me to use formulae on other sheets. I want the data to be: `col A` having `week numbers` and `column B` showing `holiday` for `year 1`, `col. C` showing `holiday` for `year 2`, etc.

```
                      Fiscal Week           
                2015    2014    2013    2012
Valentine's Day  2  2   2   3
President's Day 3   3   3   4
St. Patrick's Day   7   7   7   7
Easter  10  12  9   11
Mother's Day    15  15  15  16
Memorial Day    17  17  17  18
Flag Day    20  19  19  20
Father's Day    21  20  20  21
Independence Day    22  22  22  23
Labor Day   32  31  31  32
Columbus Day    37  37  37  37
Thanksgiving    43  43  43  43
Christmas   47  47  47  48
New Year's Day  48  48  48  49
ML King Day 51  51  51  52
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not too clear what `year 1` is, so I'm going to assume that's 2015, and `year 2` is 2014, etc.

Here's how you could set it up, if I understand correctly.  Use this index/match formula (psuedo-formula):

`=Iferror(Index([holiday names range],match([week number],[2015's week numbers in your table],0)),"")`

It looks like this:

[image]
(`=IFERROR(INDEX($A$3:$A$17,MATCH($H3,B$3:B$17,0)),"")`, in the cell next to the week numbers)

You can then drag the formula over, and the matching group (in above picture, `B3:B17`) will "slide over" as you drag the formula over.